# How can move file from one directory to another

Tags: java, list

I am sorry,I modified my entire question.

I want to move some specific files(based on `fileExtension`) from one directory to another.

For this, I plan to write 2 functions names are `ListOfFileNames` and `MovingFiles`.

If you pass `directorypath` and `filetype` as a arguments to`ListOfFileNames()`,it returns `List<File>`data.this list have entire file path.

`MovingFiles()` move files from source Directory to destination.

I tried `MovingFiles` function, in the following way.It's not working.

```
public void MovingFiles(String SourcePath,String directoryPath,String fileType) throws IOException
{
    ExternalFileExecutions ExternalFileExecutionsObject=new ExternalFileExecutions();
    List<File> fileNames=ExternalFileExecutionsObject.ListOfFileNames(SourcePath, fileType);
    for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < fileNames.size(); fileIndex++) 
    {
        fileNames[fileIndex].renameTo(new File(directoryPath+"/" + fileNames[fileIndex].getName()))
    }
}
```

I think, I need to convert `List<File>` to `List<String>`.that's why Previously I asked like that.

@tbodt replyed for my question.I failed to integrate his answer in my function.so I modified my question.

Again sorry, for modifying my entire question.

Thanks.

Comment: What would be in the `List<String>`, the files names?

Comment: Create a new list, loop over the old list, add to the new list?

Comment: List of string? You can get the file names or the absolute path, what do you exactly want to be inside the string?

Comment: And what those `String` in the list should represent? Name of the file, the content??

Comment: Do you want to get a list with each file transformed into its file path?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza sorry for late, I have fileNames in `List<File>`. I want to all the names into another list with String format(`List<String>`).because my function accepts only `String` type.so I need to change.
I hope you understand.My problem.

Comment: You need full path name or just the file name?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I want full filePath.

Comment: @All, I modified my question. can you check it once.

Comment: Why upvotes if question is not clear???

Comment: @0mile good question, multiple accounts? classmates?

Comment: We can tell you as soon as you tell us how to convert a File to a String.

Comment: @All I got it.I will Post answer for my own question.Thank you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get a `List<String>` with each element the canonical path of the corresponding file, this is how:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (File file : finalListNames)
    list.add(file.getCanonicalPath());
```

If that's not what you want, please clarify.

Comment: Until OP doesn't edit the question we cannot be sure of this (otherwise 4 people would have posted a similar answer :]).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I Modified my question.can you check it once.

Comment: Yes Thats true .. Please provide clarity on the Question

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's much more clarity. What should the strings in the new list be?

Comment: OP clarified in the comment section of his question. This answer is what he wants. -> +1

Comment: @brimborium I didn't understand the answer. Because @tbodt using `for` loop in different way.so If you understand can you explain.

Comment: Man, I miss list comprehensions so much when I am in Java.

Comment: @urtrulyfriend the `for` loop iterates over the list of files, `file` taking on the value of the file currently being iterated.

Comment: @tbodt Theoretically I understand,I new to Java side can you modify your code in easy way, Then I can also Understand..
generally Everyone use `for` loop like this. `for(int i=0;i<condition;i==){Code}`.

Comment: The for loop i use is an abbreviation for: `for (Iterator it = finalListNames.iterator(), it.hasNext(), File file = it.next())`

Answer (score 1):

If understand you, using [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), I would write it in this way:

```
    public static List<File> listOfFiles(){
        return Lists.newArrayList(new File("source.txt"), new File("test.txt"));
    }

    public static List<String> listOfFileNames(){
        return Lists.transform(listOfFiles(), new Function<File, String>() {
            public String apply(File input) {
                return input.getAbsolutePath();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant convert it. But what you can is that you can retrieve the name (what ever it is) while iterating through File list. A very handy solution would be LINQ, and select

Answer (score 0):

This my answer. I used @tbodt code in my code.

```
public void MovingFiles(String SourcePath,String directoryPath,String fileType) throws IOException
{
    ExternalFileExecutions ExternalFileExecutionsObject=new ExternalFileExecutions();
    List<File> fileNames=ExternalFileExecutionsObject.ListOfFileNames(SourcePath, fileType);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (File file : fileNames)
    list.add(file.getCanonicalPath());
    for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < list.size(); fileIndex++)
    {
        File file=new File(list.get(fileIndex));
        file.renameTo(new File(directoryPath+"/",file.getName()));
    }
}
```

Comment: In that code you create a list of file names from the list of files, then you iterate through it and recreate the file object from each one, so it's a waste. You can replace that **entire** method with just these two lines: `for (File file : new ExternalFileExecutions().ListOfFileNames(SourcePath, fileType)) file.renameTo(new File(directoryPath, file.getName()));`

Answer (score 0):

**you move a file from one directory to another directory with the same file name**

```
  try{
       File afile =new File("C:\\folder1\\file1.txt");
       if(afile.renameTo(new File("C:\\folder2\\" + afile.getName()))){
        System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
       }else{
        System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
       }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```